# Srand with threads - C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to develop a pacman c game with threads.
Main creates 2 threads in which I need to do a rand operation, but the rand's result is the same.
Here is the code :

```
int main()
{
   srand((unsigned)time(0));
   HANDLE tFantasma = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fantasma, NULL, 0, NULL);   
   srand((unsigned)time(0));
   HANDLE tFantasma2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fantasma, NULL, 0, NULL);  
   return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI fantasma(LPVOID lpParam)  
{
   int mov = rand() % 4;
   printf("%d",mov);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seed rand twice; once would be enough. Also, the time between the two calls will be the same (too little time passed) so they are seeded with the same seed. So when the sequences starts off, they are likely to start with the same number.

Comment: So, I have to set the seed just once?

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a per thread memory area. The seed used by rand() is kept in this per thread memory area, so each thread has it's own instance of seed. Each thread could do a one time call to srand() to set it's instance of seed to a different value than the other thread(s).

Comment: does each thread generate a completely new random number "list" (as if no srand was called anywhere), or will it use a local snapshot-copy of the father thread? E.g. will an srand in the father thread, before creating the child-thread, influence the child-thread's rand() results?

Comment: @Micka - each thread has it's own seed, initialized at thread creation time, and not affected by the creating (parent) thread.

Answer (score 0):

You seed rand twice; once would be enough. Also, the time between the two calls will be the same (too little time passed) so they are seeded with the same seed. So when the sequences starts off, they are likely to start with the same number. As an example of the execution sequence:

```
srand((unsigned)time(0));
HANDLE tFantasma = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fantasma, NULL, 0, NULL);   
--->fantasma() {
      mov = rand() % 4;
} 
srand((unsigned)time(0));  // reseeded; same time(); REMOVE THIS LINE
HANDLE tFantasma2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fantasma, NULL, 0, NULL);  
--->fantasma() {
      mov = rand() % 4;    // sequnce restarted: same move
}
```

Comment: Remove the second call to `srand`. It should work as it is now equivalent to `srand(time(0)); rand()%4; rand()%4;` You can make a test program with this sequence of function calls and observe the output. Lastly, it is formally possible this sequence does produce the same numbers (on first call) as it is random, just as throwing six sixes with dice is still random.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get u

Comment: I mean that `srand(time(0)); rand()%4; rand()%4;...` could produce a sequence `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1...` as that too is a random sequence. it does not mean every call to `rand()` must produce a different number (and even if it does, they could all be the same number when taken %4).

Comment: Okay, but the code I pasted on the post is simplfied, in my real code i make a printf of 'mov' in a while loop, and every single time the value is the same. Do you know if there is another function to generate random numbers in c?

Comment: Then something else is wrong in your code. `rand()` is proven. As said, write a testprogram for `rand()` and see for yourself.